# How to call activity of library module from app module

Tags: android

i want to call `Activity` of library module from the app module.but app crash.following is my code

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.main.mainactivity");
       startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

please help me.

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: Error is obvious ... there is no Activity for action "com.example.main.mainactivity" ...

Comment: Is the activity declared in the manifest of the library or of the app?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti the problem is that Intent constructor with String only parameter expects to get Action not activity class name

Answer (score 1):

> The `Intent` constructor takes two parameters:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Contecxt,Class);
```

> **1.** A Context as its first parameter (this is used because the Activity class is a subclass of Context)
>
> **2.** The Class of the app component to which the system should deliver the Intent (in this case, the activity that should be started).

**[read from docs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)**

use this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

instead of this

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.main.mainactivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: why it has upvote? [this will obviously even not compile](https://ideone.com/7e4x54) ... also this is not true: *The Intent constructor takes two parameters* .. Intent has multiple contructors